# How to select rows from array of keys?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table and the primary key is 'unique_identifier'.  I would like to select the rows from a number of keys.  I have an array that contains the keys who's data from the table I would like to select and retrieve all at once. Please set aside security concerns.

```
 $myArray = array('GMVC0001', 'GMVC0002', 'GMVC0003', 'GMVC0004', 'GMVC0005');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE unique_identifier='????????????";
 $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
 $count = $result -> num_rows;
 if($count > 0){
echo 'count: '.$count;
}else{
echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I'll let someone else post an answer which hopefully includes warnings about the proper security precautions (prepared statements/string safety/injection vulnerability/etc) but you could always [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your array, and then do `WHERE unique_identifier IN (` yourImplodedArray `)`

Comment: You are looking for the [`IN ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) SQL function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [implode function of PHP](http://php.net/manual/kr/function.implode.php) and [IN operator of SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

```
$myArray = array('GMVC0001', 'GMVC0002', 'GMVC0003', 'GMVC0004', 'GMVC0005');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE unique_identifier in ('" . implode("','", $myArray) ."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have name, roll, email in a table.After completing your sql that you have done you can access every attribute by this way.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $name = $row["name"];
  $email = $row["email"];
  $roll = $row["roll"];
}
```